# Razor syntax within html attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Check out the following:

```
<a href="/test?x=@if (Model.IsTest) { @(1) } else { @(4) }"></a>
```

Is there a better way to write this instead of the @(1) and @(4)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator:

```
<a href="/test?x=@(Model.IsTest ? 1 : 4)"></a>
```

Comment: That's a good answer, however, is it possible to output strings without using the @()?

Comment: @timeshift why would you want to?